# How do I pass a CSRF token using the python-requests library?

Tags: python, django, csrf-protection

I have an app which needs to redirect to another url from outside with some POST data. I have the CSRF token value to the other app. How do I construct a simple POST request with requests library in Python??

```
csrf_token = "kjsbfckjsdnfcksdnkl"
post_data = {'email': email, 'answer': answer}
response = request.post(URL, data=post_data)
```

Where do I add the CSRF token?

Comment: it's common to put them in cookies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either send the CSRF token as a  **POST parameter** or a **HTTP header**.

**Edit:** a [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) HTTP header is also required by Django's CSRF protection. It needs to have the same origin as the request.

**Using POST parameters:**

```
post_data = {'email': email, 'answer': answer, 'csrftoken': csrf_token_value}
headers = {'Referer': URL}
response = request.post(URL, data=post_data, headers=headers)
```

**Using HTTP headers:**

```
post_data = {'email': email, 'answer': answer}
headers = {'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token_value, 'Referer': URL}
response = request.post(URL, data=post_data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: it still says forbidden...referrer checking failed...no referrer.

Comment: Your request needs a `Referer` HTTP header that matches the domain of your request's URL. I'll edit my answer to add it.

Comment: @DeadDjangoDjoker I edited my answer to handle the no referer error.

Comment: @aumo are suggesting to put some random value for csrf_token

Comment: @Abhinay no, I just copy pasted the example from the question, putting some random value would not work, obviously. I'll update my answer to avoid confusion, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @aumo i do understand that any random value wont work here but thats what my question was , how do you get this csrf_token_value

Comment: @Abhinay you get it from the cookies of a previous GET request.

Comment: thank you man this solved my problem after hours of searching for a way to send csrf token

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use `csrf_exempt` decorator.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt .

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a recent Django with `CsrfMiddleware` add it to the `post_data` dict:

```
post_data = {'email': email, 'answer': answer, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'yourtoken'}
```

Check a form if the variable name is correct.

If you want to redirect on the same server, just call die other view function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official documentation, [which covers sending a POST request with a CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax).

CSRF tokens are stored in cookies (as far as I know). Since that's the case, you can store the cookie value as some variable, then use that value in your request.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use session objects of request library.

Moreover, if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase and A Session object has all the methods of the main Requests API.